# What datatype should I use for Aadhaar card number in MySql server database for JAVA application?

Tags: mysql

I have used BIGINT and it accepts only 10 digits.  Aadhaar id has 12 digits and hence I am getting an error. Help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL BIGINT uses 8 bytes. It should be big enough to hold 12-digit number:

```
A BIGINT uses 8 bytes, so it can store the numbers:
Signed: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775808
Unsigned: 0 to 18446744073709551615
```

Can you post error you are getting? We might help you better in that case.

Comment: #1439 - Display width out of range for 'adhar' (max = 4294967295)

Answer (score 0):

You can use varchar(12) then you can check whether it is numeric by using [ISNUMERIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in sql or [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) method in php.